# "Я стою первый" или "я стою первым"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление

Как правильно сказать: ***я стою первый*** или ***я стою первым***?

Answer (score 3):

Правильно: ***Я стою первым.***

**Пояснение**
В современном языке творительный предикативный падеж выражает  временный или случайный признак, а предикативный именительный — постоянный.
Сравните:
*Я был и наборщиком, и монтером, и водителем.

Мой дед был живописец.*

Но еще в 19 — начале 20 века именительный падеж был очень активен:
*Я сделался ремесленник* (А.С. Пушкин).

В современном языке существует явная тенденция к вытеснению именительного падежа творительным.
Когда возникают сомнения, лучше выбрать творительный падеж.